# How to download files using GeckoDriver Firefox and Selenium?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, firefox-profile

I used this code for download file , but its not working

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","D:\\WebDriverDownloads");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;"); 
profile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false );
profile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled",true );


FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);  //Shows error on this line

driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Test File to Download")).click();

Thread.sleep(5000);
```

It gives me error

[image: Error message]

And when I remove

> 'Profile'

form this `FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);`
then code run successfully but download files window is not closing and file also not downloading.

Instead of this I use Robot

```
Robot object=new Robot();
object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);         
object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

and its working fine.But Why my above code is not working?

Comment: @DebanjanB it gives same error message which shows in image , in this code also have `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);` line thats why it showing error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To download the file clicking on the *link* with text as **Test File to Download** you need to:

- Create a new *FirefoxProfile()* and set the required preferences.
- Use an instance of *FirefoxOptions()* set the *profile*.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
  profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Utility\\Downloads");
  profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
  profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
  profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
  profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
  profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
  profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
  profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
  profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
  profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
  FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
  options.setProfile(profile);
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
  driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Test File to Download"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for solution!!! its working ... but can you give little bit explanation about code?

Comment: We have just added the required _preference_ not to show the download popup through a _FirefoxProfile_ and baked it into an instance of _FirefoxOptions()_ which we have passed into the `FirefoxDriver(options)` constructor. Yes, as per best practices, you need to induce _WebDriverWait_ for the desired _elementToBeClickable()_. Any specific line you want me to explain?

Comment: Thanks for explanation... we use `profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "");` this line thats why it not showing save window ?

Comment: Corrected it right now, this property should be assigned a boolean value of `true`.

Comment: It is there twice now, once with a list of MIME types, and once with the boolean value of `true`. Either way, those options don't help and it is just not working.

Comment: @DanielZiltener That was my bad, corrected now, let me know the status.

Comment: It is as non-functional as it ever was :)