# Facing issue to handle firefox popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTIwM.png)I want to click on OK and Cancel button. Please suggest.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URF3R.png)

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
 robot.delay(300);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); //Release Enter 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Please provide source code of what you tried so far and html/page that you are trying to automate.

Comment: I tried all possible way. But did not make work  .

 /*String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
  Set<String> handles =  driver.getWindowHandles();
     for(String windowHandle  : handles)
         {
         if(!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow))
            {
            driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
            String winTitle=driver.getTitle();
            
            System.out.println(winTitle);
           driver.close(); //closing child window
           driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow); //cntrl to parent window
            }
         }*/

Comment: /* String MainWindow=driver.getWindowHandle(); 
  
  for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
      driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
      
      driver.close();
  }

*/   // To handle all new opened window.    
      /*  Set<String> s1=driver.getWindowHandles();  
        Iterator<String> i1=s1.iterator();  
      
    while(i1.hasNext())   
    {  
        String ChildWindow=i1.next();  
          
        if(!MainWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(ChildWindow))   
        {                  
                driver.switchTo().window(ChildWindow);

Comment: Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(300);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

//Release Enter
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

Comment: @SuneelSharma please provide source code in your question. not in comments

Comment: @SuneelSharma try this.. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590738/how-to-download-files-using-geckodriver-firefox-and-selenium

Comment: @PradnyaBolli, Now it worked partially,Focus shift to choose button. I want click on Cancel button.

Comment: @SuneelSharma ok i will post answer for cancel button .. but please can you update your question.which code you post in comment add that code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
Robot object=new Robot();
object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

In above code **'Escape'** key use for close popup.

you can use this also for click on 'Cancel' button:-

```
     object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
     object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
     object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
     object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
     object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
     object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

     // Press Enter
    object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

     // Release Enter
    object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Try this for click on 'Ok' button:-

```
      // Press Down
         object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);

      // Press Down
         object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);

      // Press Enter
         object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

      // Release Enter
         object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Both are working for cancel. Could please help to fix second screen (OK)

Comment: @SuneelSharma which screen?

Comment: @SuneelSharma if my answer is useful  for your question please accept it and upvote it

Comment: you want to click on 'Ok' buttton on popup??

Comment: @SuneelSharma I updated my answer ...please try that once.. and let me know if you have any problems..